# $(this).attr('id'); Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

Good day to all I am building a page and everything is going good until this last step.

Here's the code:

```
$(document) .ready(function(){
    var a;
    var b=0;
    var z="";
    var menu = [
        { name: "LOGO", items: [] },
        { name: "BANNERS", items: ["Banner", "Banner inside the Body"] },
        { name: "HEADERS", items: ["Header1", "Header2", "Header3", "Header4", "Header5"] },
        { name: "BODY TEXT", items: [] },
        { name: "LISTS", items: ["List1", "List2", "List3"] },
        { name: "TABLES", items: ["Table", "Table Text"] },
        { name: "GRAPHS", items: ["Graph1", "Graph2"] },
        { name: "HEADERS/FOOTERS SECTION", items: [] },
        { name: "SPECIAL SECTION", items: ["Special Section1", "Special Section2", "Special Section3", "Special Section4", "Special Section5"] },
    ];

    for (a=0; a<menu.length; a++){
        z+='<div class="menu-enclosure" id="butt-'+a+'"><button class="btn">'+menu[a].name+'</button>';
        while (b<menu[a].items.length) {
            z+='<button class="sub" id="subt-'+b+'">'+menu[a].items[b]+'</button>';
            b++;
        }
        b=0;
        z+="</div>";
    }

    $('.menu-holder') .append(z);

    $(document) .on('click', '.menu-enclosure', function(){
        var clicked =$(this).attr('id');
        var z = clicked.replace(/\D/g, '');
        var x =0;
        $('.content-holder') .html("");
        $('.content-holder') .append('<div class="title-bar"><span class="reg-wht">'+menu[z].name+'</span></div><BR><div class="photo-holder"><img alt="'+menu[z].name+'" src="'+menu[z].name+'"></div>');
        $('.sub') .hide();
        while (x<menu[z].items.length) { 

            $('#'+clicked+' #subt-'+x) .show();
            x++;
        }
        x=0;

        $(document) .on('click', '.sub', function(){
            var clicked =$(this).attr('id');

            $('.content-holder') .append(clicked);
        });
    });
});
```

Also, here's the JS Fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/453azpLr/embedded/result/

If you've visited my fiddle, you will notice that everything works fine except for the last part (lines 50 and so on).

As you can see when you click in the menu, the Text of whatever is clicked is then reflected to the content-holder div. But when i click on the sub menu it doesn't work.

I don't know what the main problem is or if I'm looking at it correctly but I have tried changing line 51 to various things like the once below:

```
var clicked =$(this).children("button").attr('id');

var clicked =$(this).find("button").attr('id');

var clicked =$(this).children().attr('id');
```

I also have tried changing the selector (.menu-enclosure) to the classed and ids of the buttons but to no avail.

As for the time being, I am trying to figure out if clicking gets the correct id thus the code:

```
    $('.content-holder') .append(clicked);
```

Help pls

Comment: Why should it display the title and photo? All you're appending is the ID.

Comment: Why do you have two `click` handlers for `.menu-enclosure`? Every time you run the outer handler, it will bind another handler that does `append(clicked)`.

Comment: It's almost always wrong to bind one handler inside another.

Comment: I have a little of a headache now trying to grasp your point, but basically i think you're wrong at `$(document).on('click', '.menu-enclosure', ...)` - you listen to the click on that `div` and not on the buttons within. You should put event listeners on your targeted items, not on containers.

Comment: Apart from the nested event handler, what is the issue *exactly*?

Comment: If you can all see the fiddle, when you click on the menu some of it will have a sub menu. Those sub menus are not working. That's the issue, I want it to work. I have updated my fiddle and the code in here as well.

Comment: The issue being with the submenus was a vital bit of info. :-)

Comment: Except already mentioned problems - you have one problem more: repeated ids. ID must be unique.

Comment: Repeated ids? I tried to pair them with what ever var a and var b has. Is it still considered repeating if it goes butt0, butt1, butt2 and so on?

Comment: No, but you had few 'butt0', 'butt1' and so on... Also, your 'main menu' buttons doesn't have an id, so 'clicked' then gets undefined, etc, etc... console.log(clicked), wherever you define it, and you will see...

Comment: @Selim What does `$('.content-holder') .append(clicked);` do? Why isn't it `$('.content-holder').append(clicked);` ? Have you tried deleting the space between `holder')_.append`? The underscore indicates a space that shouldn't be there.

Comment: Is that really a case? Anyhow, that's just a test if I'm getting the correct ID when I click.

Comment: You would always get the id of the parent. To know what individual child element is clicked, use `event.target`. See the answer I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work if you change the first bit to this :

```
$(document).on('click', '.menu-enclosure', function(e) {

  var clicked = e.target.id || this.id;
```

This will retrieve the actual element the click originated from instead of the parent. When changing it to this, the element that is returned when opening the menu will no longer be the wrapper div itself but the first child button. This has no id but a class, so if it turns up empty it will look at the parent div next.

Note that this won't work anymore whenever `<button class="btn">` would get it's own id. You could leave the second check out if these buttons get the id transferred from the `.menu-enclosure` parent.

https://jsfiddle.net/37eyppnh/

By the way, when the ids from `.menu-enclosure` *are* transferred to the buttons this would also work :

```
$(document).on('click', '.menu-enclosure button', function() {

  var clicked = this.id;
```

Comment: is there a way to get the last child in e.target.children.id ?

Comment: If I understand correctly - recognise if it's the last button, regardless of id or anything?

Comment: yep. recognize the last child. i have been searching and trying to apply the last child option but i can't get it to work.

Comment: Here's one approach : `$(this).find('button').length-1 == $(e.target).index()`. https://jsfiddle.net/zjffnn1d/